# How to subscribe to an element's (that not exist yet) event

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, rxjs

I want to create an observable that subscribes to an event on an element that may not exist yet. If the element isn't found, it retries until the element is found.

The problem is TypeScript doesn't like it.

I get an error when I call `.pipe(...)` on the observable. The errors are on whatever I put in `pipe`, in this case `retryWhen(...)`. No errors if I don't use `pipe`.

Here's my code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { retryWhen, delay } from 'rxjs/operators'

export const scroll$ = new Observable((subscriber) => {
  const scrollbox = document.querySelector('.section-scrollbox')

  if (scrollbox) {
    scrollbox.addEventListener('scroll', handleEvent)

    return scrollbox.removeEventListener('scroll', handleEvent)
  } else {
    subscriber.error()
  }

  function handleEvent(this: HTMLDivElement) {
    subscriber.next(this)
  }
}).pipe(
  retryWhen((errors) => errors.pipe(delay(1000))),
)
```

I get these errors:

> Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.
>
> Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement'.ts(2345)

How can I set the type to `Observable<HTMLDivElement>` in this scenario?

BTW, this isn't an Angular question. I'm using this in a Chrome extension content script.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html does the same job...

Comment: Could be unrelated but combining `return` and a void function call is a bad idea that may confuse TS compiler so I suggest separating them.

Comment: you want to check if the element exists in a 1 sec interval, and if it exists subscribe to it's 'scroll' event?

Comment: @benshabatnoam now that you put it that way, interval + switchMap would be a better solution...

Comment: 10x for your question, it was fun to get it to work. check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This observable will do the job:

```
const scroll$ = timer().pipe(
  switchMap(() => of(document.querySelector('.section-scrollbox'))),
  switchMap(bodyDiv => fromEvent(bodyDiv, 'scroll')),
  retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
    delay(1000)
  ))
);
```

---

## Explanation:

1. [timer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html) - emits 1 value then completes.

   this is just for initializing the observable to look for your element.
2. switchMap(() => of(document.querySelector('.section-scrollbox')))

   will return your element if exists
3. switchMap(bodyDiv => fromEvent(bodyDiv, 'scroll'))

   if your element **exists** will return **only** the scroll event from now (won't look for the element any more)
4. retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000)))

   if your element **doesn't exists** will retry step 2 to get your element again, **after** 
   a delay of 1 second.

> Checkout this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-typescript-rxjs-subscribe-2-element-event-on-element-create)